# Can't find windows phone 7 template under VC# Express 2010 but only on VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I have both VC# Express 2010 and VS 2010 on my machine. I installed Windows phone 7 toolkit but I can only find Windows Phone 7 application template under VS 2010 not VC# Express. How can I also get it on VC# Express 2010 ?

On MS page it is advertized Windows Phone 7 for Express Edition

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Phone/

Answer (score 1):

The Express version does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you had figured it out, but once you install the SDK you will find "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone" in the start menu. Should use this and not the regular vC#2010 express IDE

Ofcourse this question was asked 2 years back :) just in case for users who stumble upon this